# E/configParser - ReferenceError: element is not defined

Tags: javascript, protractor

I want to implement page object and to be more specific want to read element declared in function in it's prototype.

Tried different ways and those are working fine, however curious if implementation is possible this way also.

Spec File

```
var login_page = require('../pages/login_page');
describe('login page and properties', function () {
    it('verify application launch with URL', function () {
        browser.get('appUrl').then(function () {
            browser.getTitle().then(function (appTitle) {
                expect(appTitle).toBe('Protractor practice website');
            });
        });
        login_page.enterUsername();
    });
});
```

login_page.js:

```
var login_page = function() {  
    this.username = element(by.id('username'));
};

login_page.prototype.enterUsername = function() {
    this.username.sendKeys('anyString');
};

module.exports = new login_page();
```

Error:

```
> protractor conf.js

[22:05:42] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[22:05:42] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[22:05:42] E/configParser - ReferenceError: element is not defined
```

Comment: Did you import element? You should have a line like the following at the top of your file: `import { by, element } from 'protractor';`

Comment: yes, already tried that. Below is the error reference:

`> protractor conf.js

[22:27:24] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[22:27:24] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[22:27:24] E/configParser - <path>\javaScript\pages\login_page.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { by, element } from 'protractor'`

Comment: Show your conf.js

Answer (score 0):

### Async / await

Think about using async / await. You'll need to change your config `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`. This will unchain all the thenables.

### Element not defined

Why is `element` not defined? Probably because the module is loaded before the global object `element` is defined. Consider instead creating the new object in a `beforeAll` so we know that `element` does exist.

### Fixes with async / await and element not defined

**Spec File:**

```
const LoginPage = require('../pages/login_page').LoginPage;
let login_page = null;

describe('login page and properties', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    login_page = new LoginPage();
  });

  it('verify application launch with URL', async () => {
    await browser.get('appUrl');
    const appTitle = await browser.getTitle();
    expect(appTitle).toBe('Protractor practice website');
    await login_page.enterUsername();
  });
});
```

**login_page.js:**

If you use JavaScript classes, you don't have to use prototypes.

```
export class LoginPage {
  username = element(by.id('username'));

  /**
   * enter the user name.
   * returns the promise to send keys
   */
  async enterUsername() {
    return this.username.sendKeys('anyString');
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the details, appreciate that however I wanted to know why javaScript behaves this way.
The code you shared will work absolutely fine even I don't want to initiate object in beforeEach.
As part of solution I have removed the require(page.po.js) where I was keeping all my page objects from the conf.js, I will export pages as per the standards instead.
Anyways, thanks a lot for investigating and providing your valuable time and comments.

Comment: This is because Jasmine is loading the JavaScript modules. In this particular case you are referencing `element` and Protractor creates the `element` object during the bring up steps of Protractor. In this situation, if `element` has not been created yet, you are going to get an error. The preferred case is to new up your page object during a beforeAll step so you ensure that `element` does exist at the time of your test execution.